# How do you install pants for python?

Tags: python, pants

How do you install `pants` in Python?

I've been searching a while in Google and couldn't get a straight answer for it.

I'm currently using Linux Mint and Python version 2.7.3.

Comment: You couldn't find anything on Google? I search "Python pants" and the first link sent me to that site in the answer below, where there is an installation section

Comment: probably best to use pip.  Lookup pip install pants

Answer (score 2):

To give a little detail, installing a release from pypi is probably the best way. Pants has a shell script that handles that install. This is all available in the documentation but here it is without needing an outside link:

```
curl -L -O https://pantsbuild.github.io/setup/pants && chmod +x pants && touch pants.ini
```

You are ready to go. Run `./pants --version` and that will create the pants virtualenv for you.